# Renaming Excel to CSV Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, csv, save-as

I am trying to write a Macro in VBA using Excel 2010 that is linked to a button in a worksheet (located in Cell A1). When the button is pressed, a CSV should be generated that deletes columns A and B, so that column C effectively becomes column A. I am trying to also name the newly generated CSV based on the cell contents from cell A30 within the worksheet, but when I run the macro I am getting an error on the SaveAs function. I believe this is because cell A30 is deleted later on in the script. My question is where there is a way to use the Range (A30) to name the new CSV while still deleting that cell later on within the new CSV all within the same sub? I'm still new to VBA, so it is unclear to me why this is an issue when I would think that each command is executed sequentially, so once the CSV is saved with the new name, I would think I'd be able to delete the source of the file name.

```
Sub rpSaveCSV()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

'Saves current sheet of tracker as a CSV
ws.SaveAs "Y:\Drive\Youth " & Range("A30") & " .csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV

'Copies entire sheet and pastes values to get rid of formulas
  ws.Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    ActiveSheet.Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Deletes first two columns and all remaining columns without content
Range("A:B").EntireColumn.Delete
Range("BI:XFD").EntireColumn.Delete

'Saves panel CSV
ActiveWorkbook.Save

'Opens Tracker up again
Workbooks.Open Filename:="Y:\Drive\Tracker.xlsm"

End Sub
```

Comment: See how you got `Dim ws As Worksheet` there? That's declaring a local variable. You can very well do `Dim fileName As String` and do `fileName = Range("A30").Value`, and reuse it later down the road.

Comment: *I am getting an error on the SaveAs function* - **what** error are you getting *exactly*?

Comment: As for deleting files, you can do that with the `Kill` keyword... provided that the kill target is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a variable to hold the string value:

```
Dim filename as String
filename = Range("A30")

'verify that "Y:\Drive\Youth " & filename & " .csv" is a valid file name:
Debug.Print "Y:\Drive\Youth " & filename & " .csv" ' looks right? Ctrl+G to find out
ws.SaveAs "Y:\Drive\Youth " & filename & " .csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV

'...delete columns...

'...do stuff...

Debug.Print filename 'value is still here!
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I am still getting the same Run-time error '1004': Method 'SaveAs' of object'_Worksheet' failed.

Comment: @Ryan one problem is that `Range("A30")` is implicitly referring to whatever worksheet is currently active: it's like writing `ActiveSheet.Range("A30").Value`, which may or may not be what you need to be looking at. Use more explicit code, specify what the sheet is and use that object to qualify that `Range` call. What's the value of `filename`? Did you check with Ctrl+G? Does it look right?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend learning to use arrays with Excel data.  It can often be far simpler than trying to replication Excel Application functions in VBA. And it is far more efficient/fast.

Here is a function that feeds the data to an array, and then prints the array to a csv (text) file.

```
Sub CreateCsvFromWorkSheet(leftColumn, rightColumn, FileName)
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fso.CreateTextFile(FileName, True)

    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    ar = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, leftColumn), ws.Cells(lastRow, rightColumn))
    For i = 1 To UBound(ar, 1)
        strLine = ""
        For j = 1 To UBound(ar, 2)
            strLine = strLine & ar(i, j) & ","
        Next
        strLine = Left(strLine, Len(strLine) - 1)
        f.WriteLine strLine
    Next
    f.Close
End Sub
```

You can call the function like this:

```
Sub TestRun()
    FileName = "Y:\Drive\Youth " & Range("A30") & " .csv"
    CreateCsvFromWorkSheet 3, 60, FileName
    MsgBox "Complete."
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you saying writing the CSV file one cell at a time will be "far more efficient" than using Excel's built-in SaveAs CSV format?

Comment: @Mathieu No.  But it may be faster than copying and pasting all cells in the worksheet, then deleting two columns.  I really don't know if it's faster in this case.  My point was that it is extremely useful to learn arrays.

Comment: And when you write an Excel range to an array, then iterate through the elements of the array, that is not the same as iterating through "one cell at a time".  When you iterate cells in a worksheet there is communication that occurs between the Excel application and VBA; and that takes time.  Arrays are native to VBA and are lightning fast compared to iterating through a range "one cell at a time".

Comment: Yes, I know that, thank you. I meant "one cell/value at a time". You're still iterating thousands of times to write as many things to a file that could be written with one single native operation, while reinventing the CSV wheel.

Comment: I just did some testing, and the range-to-array-to-csv method is definitely slower than the Excel `SaveAs` method (0.9 seconds vs. 0.3 seconds when run on 1 million cells of data).  Honestly though, I still favor the former approach, for the simple fact that when I want to save data from the current workbook as a csv, I want to *export* it, not "save" the code and all my fancy formulas in a file format that doesn't even support them.  That's why the OP has a line that "'Opens Tracker up again".  What he really wanted was an *export*.

Comment: CSV is exactly that. Ever opened a CSV file in Notepad? There's a reason Excel will only save/export the active sheet. And it will always properly delimit the data so a cell containing a comma won't break your file. Can't be sure of that with this approach. Exporting worksheet data to CSV is a solved problem.

Comment: What I meant was that when you use SaveAs, Excel closes the xlsm file, and what's left open is some sort of hybrid "file" that contains csv data (which can be re-saved) as well as formulas, formatting, and code (that can't be re-saved).  So if you want to *export* data from your application, you really have to create another workbook, paste your data into it, save that workbook as a csv, and then close it.

Comment: I agree it's nice that Excel adds text delimiters to a value if it contains a comma.  I would just as soon add those delimiters myself, so that it is obvious how my file is delimited... or make it a pipe delimited file, which you can't do with `SaveAs`.

Comment: Look, do your thing, I'll do mine. `Workbook.SaveAs FileFormat:=xlCSV` **is** an export, and the fact that formats and formulas and code remain in the loaded document is literally a proof of that. Also FYI the C in CSV stands for "comma", not "whatever delimiter one feels like using". Anyway, feels like I'm discussing SQL injection mitigation with someone who would rather manually escape single quotes and keep concatenating their WHERE clause than do the right thing and parameterize their stuff. Have a nice day!

Comment: Hey, you did a great job of quickly solving the OP's problem, and I admire that.